# Connecting a springboot application with mysql server over ssl

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, ssl

I need to connect my spring boot application with a remote my sql server that is on ssl. I am using JPA in my app. I have read about ssl and the certificates required and that I would need MySql Conector/J for establising a conection. I was just wondering what kind of approach I should opt as I am a complete beginner and cant find an effective tuturiol over internet. Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reference is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html (Scroll down a bit to security part)

Basically you need a PKCS12 / JKS format of your app's certificate & server CA certificate. Then add it into the JDBC URL.

Example: In `application.yml`, assume we're using PKCS12 format, use SSL and verify server CA. Assume the client (app) certificate filename is `client-cert.p12` and the CA certificate filename is `server-ca.p12`.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: >
      jdbc:mysql://{DATABASE_IP}/{DATABASE_NAME}?
      useSSL=true&
      requireSSL=true&
      clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file://{SOME_DIRECTORY}/client-cert.p12&
      clientCertificateKeyStoreType=PKCS12&
      clientCertificateKeyStorePassword={KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
      verifyServerCertificate=true&
      trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file://{SOME_DIRECTORY}/server-ca.p12&
      trustCertificateKeyStoreType=PKCS12&
      trustCertificateKeyStorePassword={KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
    username: {USERNAME}
    password: {PASSWORD}
```

If using JKS, the file format usually is `jks` and the type is `JKS`. If you don't need to verify CA, set `verifyServerCertificate = false` and you don't need the `trustCertificateKeyStore` stuff (last 3 lines)

Comment: I suppose I have to send some kind of request for getting server CA certificate, after that I can use it to configure. How to request that certificate and How to store it in our store?

Comment: You need to ask the owner / admin of your server for the certificate files. The DB server should store the same key files too. It's us human *manually* copying key files.

Comment: What if owner stores the certificate in some online directory, can i pass the "URL" in appli cation properties for the certificate ?

Comment: I think just change the `file://` into `http://`, but I never tried it before

Answer (score 0):

If you have managed to get the client certificate, clientkeystore.jks in below expression
you can supply the below as the url and can connect:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://XXXX:3306/mydatabase?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8&verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/opt/clientkeystore.jks&clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=mypass&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/opt/truststore.jks&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=mypass
```

Comment: Well how to communicate with the server for getting the client certificate, as well as the key store and where and how to store that certificate once fetched?

Comment: once you have the certificate, you have multiple choices: 1) Import the server certificate into cacerts present in jdk at $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts 2) or provide it as an argument to  your java program with -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path_to_truststore> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<truststore_password>